# clamd PING give ERROR: initgroups() failed?

Tags: 12.04, services, clamav

My ubuntu version is 12.04.

I have installed clamav as root user using the below commands.

```
apt-get install clamav
apt-get install clamav-daemon
```

But when I use the below command

```
clamd PING
```

It gives below error message.

```
ERROR: initgroups() failed
```

Am I missed anything?

Comment: I think you are already running clamd process.

Comment: If you are wanting to start/stop clamd (which is how I came to be looking here..), you need to do the following: `sudo service clamav-daemon stop` 
To start it again do `sudo service clamav-daemon start`